# CSS3 animation - letter from to bottom

Tags: css, animation

I have an animation using pure css - I have a div - containing a bunch of p tags - I want to drop a letter at a time - that works - but why dont I see the letter at the bottom?

I want to see each letter stay in the bottom of the page - I have tried to use bottom pixels but the result is the same.

Any ideas what I am missing?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<style>


#main
{
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#main > p
{
  float:left;
  position: relative;
}

.letter:nth-child(1) {
    animation: bottom 5s  1s;
}
.letter:nth-child(2) {
    animation: bottom 5s  2s;
}
.letter:nth-child(3) {
    animation: bottom 5s  3s;
}


@keyframes bottom 
{ 
   0% {bottom: 100%;}
   100%{bottom:0%;}
}


</style>


<body>


<div id="main">
    <p class='letter'>A</p>
    <p class='letter'>B</p>
    <p class='letter'>C</p>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should make your letter or p tags be absolutley positioned. You will get better performance that way.

Second add `forwards` to your animation.

`animation: bottom 5s  3s forwards;`

That will make your letters stay at the end of animation.

Check out this pen: https://codepen.io/ivandoric/pen/VXgMNE

Comment: Thank you so much :) /henrik

Comment: I just made a change to the pen. They are not aligned because they are abslutley positioned. I corrected that in the new version so check it out: https://codepen.io/ivandoric/pen/VXgMNE you must set position for each letter.

Comment: Hi! Nice, how can I do it so when it starts I see all the letters at the top - A B C - and from there drop a letter at a time?

Comment: Like A B C is fixed from the start - then letter A is animated, then letter B and so on /Henrik

Comment: Updated the pen again: https://codepen.io/ivandoric/pen/VXgrPR better to use top position then bottom. Then you get the desired effect. The letters will be visible and then start falling.

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: No problem. Just remeber to mark my answer as useful and correct.